# The code is working fine in codeSandbox, But showing error while doing in the IDE as "can't define property "email": Object is not extensible"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, codesandbox

I am trying to implement a simple code in react.js which user can input the data using form and unless the page is refreshed the data will show in the table.

I have implemented a code in Code Sandbox and it worked as expected. Then I copied that code and used it in the IDE. Now the same code is showing error as ==> "TypeError: can't define property "email": Object is not extensible". (I am using intellij IDE ultimate edition)

This is the link for sandbox => [Link for the code in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-mountain-bepg9?file=/src/App.js)

The code it self if the sand box is not working ==>

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class CustomDetails extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        items: [{email: '', country: '', new_case: '', total_case: '', total_death: ''}],
        message: ''
    }
    this.newData = React.createRef();
    this.addForm = React.createRef();

}

addData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {items} = this.state;
    
    const newData = () => ({
        email:this.addForm.email.value,
        country:this.addForm.country.value,
        new_case:this.addForm.new_case.value,
        total_case:this.addForm.total_case.value,
        total_death:this.addForm.total_death.value
    })
    const isOnTheList = items.includes(newData.country);

    if (isOnTheList) {
        this.setState(({
            message: 'This country details are already added.'
        }))
    } else {
        this.setState({
            items: [...this.state.items, newData()],
        })
    }
    this.addForm.reset();
}




render() {
    const {items, message}=this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
            
                <div>
                    <form ref={input => this.addForm = input} onSubmit={(e) => {
                        this.addData(e)
                    }}>
         
                            <label>User Email :</label><br/>
                            <input required ref={input => this.newData["email"] = input} name="email" value={this.state.items.email}
                                   type="email"
                                   placeholder="Enter email"/><br></br>

                           
                                <label>Country :</label><br/>
                                <input required ref={input => this.newData["country"] = input} name="country" value={this.state.items.country}
                                       type="text"
                                       placeholder="Enter country"/><br></br>
                           

                            
                                <label>New Cases :</label><br/>
                                <input required ref={input => this.newData["new_case"] = input}
                                name="new_case"
                                       value={this.state.items.new_case} type="text"
                                       placeholder="Enter no of new cases"/><br></br>
                           

                           
                                <label>Total cases :</label><br/>
                                <input required ref={input => this.newData["total_case"] = input}
                                name="total_case"
                                       value={this.state.items.total_case} type="text"
                                       placeholder="Enter no of total cases"/><br></br>
                           

                           
                                <label>Total death :</label><br/>
                                <input required ref={input => this.newData["total_death"] = input}
                                name="total_death"
                                       value={this.state.items.total_death} type="text"
                                       placeholder="Enter no of total deaths"/><br></br>
                            

                            <button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                Submit</button><br></br>
                       
                    </form>

                </div>
                <div>
                    
                   
                    {
                        message !== '' && <p>{this.setState.message}</p>
                    }
                    <table striped="true" bordered="true" hover="true">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th>New cases</th>
                            <th>Total cases</th>
                            <th>Total deaths</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {items.map((item,index) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={index}>

                                    <td>{item.email}</td>
                                    <td>{item.country}</td>
                                    <td>{item.new_case}</td>
                                    <td>{item.total_case}</td>
                                    <td>{item.total_death}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
              
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}}export default CustomDetails;
```

The output in sandbox -->
[image: Sand box output]

The error while running it in IDE -->
[image: ide error]

Comment: `this.state.items` is array not object use: `this.state.items[0].email` or change `this.state.items` to object

Comment: Tried that.. But getting the same error. But the above code is working fine in sandbox

Comment: change in `constructor`:`this.newData = {email: '', country: '', new_case: '', total_case: '', total_death: ''};` and `this.addForm = {email: '', country: '', new_case: '', total_case: '', total_death: ''};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a point to using React refs in this case as you can easily access the field values from the form's `onSubmit` event object.

1. Initial state should be an empty array.

   ```
   this.state = {
     items: [],
   };
   ```
2. The `addData` callback needs `this` of the class bound to it.
3. `addData` should access the form field values from the `onSubmit` event object. The `newData` should be an object of the form field values you want to push into your `items` state array. Use a functional state update to update from the previous state. When searching the `items` array for existing entries you need to use an array function that allows examining object properties as `Array.prototype.includes` really only check reference equality, you want to search for an item that has a matching `country` property using `Array.prototype.some` to return a boolean.

   ```
   addData = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     const { items } = this.state;

     const newData = {
       email: e.target.email.value,
       country: e.target.country.value,
       new_case: e.target.new_case.value,
       total_case: e.target.total_case.value,
       total_death: e.target.total_death.value
     };

     const isOnTheList = items.some(item => item.country === newData.country);

     if (isOnTheList) {
       this.setState({
         message: "This country details are already added."
       });
     } else {
       this.setState((prevState) => ({
         items: [...prevState.items, newData]
       }));
     }
     e.target.reset();
   };
   ```
4. Since you've uncontrolled inputs you should remove the old "legacy" style ref attachments and `value` prop. Example:

   ```
   <input
     required
     name="email"
     type="email"
     placeholder="Enter email"
   />
   ```
5. You've a typo when trying to render an error message, `{message !== "" && <p>{this.setState.message}</p>}`, it should be `{message !== "" && <p>{this.state.message}</p>}`.

## Demo

[image: Edit the-code-is-working-fine-in-codesandbox-but-showing-error-while-doing-in-the-id]

Full code:

```
class CustomDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      message: ""
    };
  }

  addData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { items } = this.state;

    const newData = {
      email: e.target.email.value,
      country: e.target.country.value,
      new_case: e.target.new_case.value,
      total_case: e.target.total_case.value,
      total_death: e.target.total_death.value
    };
    const isOnTheList = items.includes(newData.country);

    if (isOnTheList) {
      this.setState({
        message: "This country details are already added."
      });
    } else {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        items: [...prevState.items, newData]
      }));
    }
    e.target.reset();
  };

  render() {
    const { items, message } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.addData}>
              <label>User Email :</label>
              <br />
              <input
                required
                name="email"
                type="email"
                placeholder="Enter email"
              />
              <br></br>

              <label>Country :</label>
              <br />
              <input
                required
                name="country"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter country"
              />
              <br></br>

              <label>New Cases :</label>
              <br />
              <input
                required
                name="new_case"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter no of new cases"
              />
              <br></br>

              <label>Total cases :</label>
              <br />
              <input
                required
                name="total_case"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter no of total cases"
              />
              <br></br>

              <label>Total death :</label>
              <br />
              <input
                required
                name="total_death"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter no of total deaths"
              />
              <br></br>

              <button variant="primary" type="submit">
                Submit
              </button>
              <br></br>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div>
            {message !== "" && <p>{this.state.message}</p>}
            <table striped="true" bordered="true" hover="true">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Country</th>
                  <th>New cases</th>
                  <th>Total cases</th>
                  <th>Total deaths</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {items.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td>{item.email}</td>
                      <td>{item.country}</td>
                      <td>{item.new_case}</td>
                      <td>{item.total_case}</td>
                      <td>{item.total_death}</td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for that best explanation. In order to add only 1 data to a country name i have added a error message when user input another data for the same country. I order to get that message do in need to replace the key value as item.country ?

Comment: @Deepika Totally correct, the `.includes` array function won't work for object properties, I suggest using the `.some` to check if *some* item has a matching `country` property value. I updated my answer and linked codesandbox. Just noticed you also had a type when trying to render the message, it's `{message !== "" && <p>{this.state.message}</p>}`, you had `this.setState.message`.

Comment: Thank-you so much. from this explanation I was able to understand the code and what I have done wrong.

Comment: If I want to calculate the total (if 4 uses input data calculate the 4 data of the followings) of new_cases, total_cases and total_deaths , and add them in the table by creating new columns how to do that using functions?   @Drew

Comment: @Deepika Sounds like you want to compute row totals for new cases, total cases, and total deaths, and add a row summarizing the totals, is this correct? Or you want new columns? Either way, you can reduce the `items` array data into the totals I think you're asking about. If you provide a little clarity and still need help I can help here.

Comment: Like, The first person added the new_cases as 10. The second person added as 45. The 3rd person added as 24. So in the end or in a new table need to show the total new_cases (10+45+24=79). Like wise need to show the total for total_death and total recover @Drew

Comment: @Deepika https://codesandbox.io/s/the-code-is-working-fine-in-codesandbox-but-showing-error-while-doing-in-the-id-forked-okcgi?file=/src/App.js:1036-1454

Comment: I have tried like this. But can't we do this in a function out from the render().

Comment: @Deepika You can factor this logic into a function if you really need to, this is a trivial change.

Comment: Thankyou so much sir, I'll do that. This is really helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is the below line (and if you remove it, it will be the next `input` line) :-

```
<input required ref={input => this.newData["email"] = input} name="email" value={this.state.items.email} type="email" placeholder="Enter email"/><br></br>
```

In your `ref`'s callback, you are assigning a `ref` object with a field name of `email` to `input`.

If you go ahead and `console.log(Object.isExtensible(this.newData)` in your `render` method, you will see it will show `false`. So you're trying to add an `email` property to an `object` which doesn't allow it.
Your **codesandbox** is **silently failing** but your **IDE** is running in **strict mode**.

You need to initialize `this.newData` to an `object` by making `this.newData` equivalent to `{email: '', country: '', new_case: '', total_case: '', total_death: ''};` as per your use-case. So your `this.newData` will not be a React `ref` anymore but just an instance variable for your Class.

Here are MDN links that helped :-

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isExtensible

Do see @Drew's answer on how to deal with inputs in a better way.